# Syntaxis error in Create View MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, view

I'm trying to create a View that draws the last entry from Logs (Registro tracto and registro Operador) corresponding to the trip (viaje) of a LoadOrder (Orden de carga) and shows every 'Load Order with info'  [E-R diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wNiL0.png)

I've sketched the next view but I can't make it work because of Sytaxis error.

```
    `CREATE VIEW `OrdenEnCurso` AS
    SELECT OC.'NO_ORDEN_DE_CARGA' AS 'ORDEN DE CARGA'
        , OC.'ID_VIAJE' AS 'ID DE VIAJE'
        , RT.'TRACTO_ECO' AS 'TRACTO'
        , ROO.'NOMBRE' AS 'N.OPERADOR', 
        GF.S AS 'GASTOS FINANCIADOS'
    FROM 
    'ORDEN_DE _CARGA' AS OC 
    INNER JOIN (SELECT 'TRACTO_ECO','ID_VIAJE' FROM 'REGISTRO_TRACTO' GROUP BY 
  'ID_VIAJE' HAVING MAX('FECHAHORA') ) AS RT 
        ON OC.ID_VIAJE=RT.ID_VIAJE
    INNER JOIN (SELECT CONCAT_WS(',',O.AP_PAT,O.AP_MAT,O.NOMBRE) AS 'NOMBRE' 
  FROM 'OPERADOR' AS O 
        INNER JOIN (SELECT 'ID_VIAJE','NO_OPERADOR' FROM 'REGISTRO_OPERADOR' 
    GROUP BY 'ID_VIAJE' HAVING MAX('FECHAHORA') ) AS RO 
            ON RO.NO_OPERADOR=O.NO_OPERADOR) AS ROO
        ON OC.ID_VIAJE=ROO.ID_VIAJE
    INNER JOIN (SELECT 'OC',SUM(IMPORTE) AS S FROM 'GASTOS_F_CLIENTE' 
GROUP BY 
    'NO_ORDEN_DE_CARGA') AS GF ON OC.NO_ORDEN_DE_CARGA=GF.OC;
```

Also, as you may see, I would like to concat the Operator name separetaed with a coma. And Finally sum how much the client will pay extra per LoadOrder.

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''NO_ORDEN_DE_CARGA' AS 'ORDEN DE CARGA' , OC.'ID_VIAJE' AS 'ID DE VIAJE' , R' at line 2   0.000 sec

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''NO_ORDEN_DE_CARGA' AS 'ORDEN DE CARGA'   , OC.'ID_VIAJE' AS 'ID DE VIAJE'   , R' at line 2 0.000 sec

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are confusing the use of ticks and quotation marks

Try this SQL statement

```
CREATE VIEW OrdenEnCurso AS
    SELECT OC.NO_ORDEN_DE_CARGA AS `ORDEN DE CARGA`,
        OC.ID_VIAJE AS `ID DE VIAJE`,
        RT.TRACTO_ECO AS TRACTO,
        ROO.NOMBRE AS `N.OPERADOR`, 
        GF.S AS `GASTOS FINANCIADOS`
    FROM ORDEN_DE_CARGA AS OC 
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT TRACTO_ECO, ID_VIAJE
        FROM REGISTRO_TRACTO 
        GROUP BY ID_VIAJE
        HAVING MAX(FECHAHORA) 
        ) AS RT 
        ON OC.ID_VIAJE = RT.ID_VIAJE
    INNER JOIN (
            SELECT CONCAT_WS(`,`,O.AP_PAT,O.AP_MAT,O.NOMBRE) AS NOMBRE
            FROM OPERADOR AS O 
        INNER JOIN (
            SELECT ID_VIAJE, NO_OPERADOR 
            FROM REGISTRO_OPERADOR
            GROUP BY ID_VIAJE 
            HAVING MAX(FECHAHORA) 
            ) AS RO 
            ON RO.NO_OPERADOR=O.NO_OPERADOR
        ) AS ROO
        ON OC.ID_VIAJE=ROO.ID_VIAJE
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT OC,SUM(IMPORTE) AS S 
        FROM GASTOS_F_CLIENTE
        GROUP BY NO_ORDEN_DE_CARGA
        ) AS GF 
        ON OC.NO_ORDEN_DE_CARGA=GF.OC;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, It's been almost a year since I learned MySQL but haven´t practiced since then.